# Failed to Load Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

so I just started to work with Android Studio and I'm completely noob when it comes to Android developing. So I just installed Android Studio 1.5.1 and created my first project. Now I try to create an emulator to run my app, but I still get the failed to load error, regardless which configuration I choose for the Emulator.

Here is what I get:

[image: error image]!

Do you have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try : file->Invalidate caches/Restart, then click on "Invalidate and restart".